# All possible combinations with 10 data sets

Tags: excel, excel-2010

What I'm trying to do is create a table with all possible combinations of the outcomes of ten independent pass/fail (0/1, true/false, yes/no, +/-, however you want to define it) tests. So for example, if all ten tests pass, I would have a column of ten pass values. Since there's 1024 possible combinations, I'd really rather not have to type them all out.

I don't really need it to be very interactive as I only need the table made once, but I would love to see how it's done to learn/if I need to create a similar table for different data sets in the future.

I tried a method listed on here using the Microsoft QUERY input but to be honest I didn't really understand it. A sample of the output would look like:

```
Combo 1:    Combo 2:     Combo 3:
1             1            1
1             1            1
1             1            1
1             1            1
1             1            1
1             1            1
1             1            1
1             1            1
1             1            0
1             0            0
```

etc for all 1024 possibilities. So every value in each column will be either a `0` or `1`, and no two columns are the same.

Comment: Please show us what you've already tried.  Also we would need a sample of the output that you want.

Comment: What format is the data in now?

Comment: Just 10 data sets with only the values 0 and 1.

Comment: How is it formatted?  Show a sample of the source.

Comment: I don't really have it formatted. I guess the source would like:

Set 1 = (0,1)
Set 2 = (0,1)
Set 3 = (0,1)

and so on, if that helps

Comment: So, the data isn't in a file anywhere?  You've yet to enter it?  What is generating the data?  Is there a way to control the output?

Comment: No, there isn't really any data being generated. I just want to create a table that contains all the possible ways to order 10 values that are either 0 or 1. I'm not really sure what data you would need in order to create that chart. Sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: So you want all of the permutations of 10 x (0,1) result?

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot tomorrow and let you know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste this into a module:

```
Sub test()
    Dim c As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To 1023
        Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, 1) = "'" & Dec2Bin(i, 10)
    Next i

    Sheet1.Columns(1).TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array _
        (5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    For c = 11 To 1034
        For n = 2 To 11
            Sheet1.Cells(n, c) = Sheet1.Cells(c - 10, n - 1)
            Sheet1.Cells(1, c) = "Case " & c - 10 & ":"
        Next n
    Next c

    Sheet1.Columns("A:J").Delete
End Sub
Function Dec2Bin(ByVal DecimalIn As Variant, _
              Optional NumberOfBits As Variant) As String
    Dec2Bin = ""
    DecimalIn = Int(CDec(DecimalIn))
    Do While DecimalIn <> 0
        Dec2Bin = Format$(DecimalIn - 2 * Int(DecimalIn / 2)) & Dec2Bin
        DecimalIn = Int(DecimalIn / 2)
    Loop
    If Not IsMissing(NumberOfBits) Then
       If Len(Dec2Bin) > NumberOfBits Then
          Dec2Bin = "Error - Number exceeds specified bit size"
       Else
          Dec2Bin = Right$(String$(NumberOfBits, _
                    "0") & Dec2Bin, NumberOfBits)
       End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Just put it in, seems like its exactly what I wanted! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in Row1 copied down to Row512:

```
=DEC2BIN(ROW()-1,10) and

=1&RIGHT(N1,9)
```

where `N` is the column containing the first formula.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2013, you can use the new BITAND function.

Create a column with the numbers between 0 and 1023 ascending.

Assuming that's column A, use a formula in this form in the 10 columns to the right.

```
Column B: =BITAND($A2,512)/512
Column C: =BITAND($A2,256)/256
Column D: =BITAND($A2,128)/128
```

and so on.

This technique uses a bitwise and to test if a particular bit is set in the input column. You divide by the value of the bit you're testing so that the result is 0 or 1.

Comment: Seems I can't do it on this computer with Excel 2010, but I'll give it a shot when I get home. Thanks you!

Comment: Oh, darn, I didn't notice that it was a new function in Excel 2013.

Comment: No problem, sounds like it should work but I have no experience with bitwise functions in Excel hahah